# how to set outside small 8 box for resize with border?

Tags: html, css

I made one box and 8 side small boxes for resize . simply displaying these 8 small boxes at the border of main box .see this : http://jsfiddle.net/kamlesh0606/jrQ7A/1/

but when I added border to the main box, these 8 small boxes appear inside the main box ..  see this : http://jsfiddle.net/kamlesh0606/cSvXP/

so help me so as  ***how to place these 8 small boxes outside the main box with border?***

Thanks

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/uttara/cSvXP/2/) what you want http://jsfiddle.net/uttara/cSvXP/2/

Comment: like this but i will add border size then again small 8 box  inside  in main box , so i need that this 8 box any condition , display outside of main box .......

Comment: can you plz explain a lil more what actually you want

Comment: i make 8 size resize box and this all box have any class for assess in jquery for resize this box .... so this 8 box display outside of main div(box) ..

Comment: Have a look at: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp, that should explain why this is happening.

Answer (score 2):

well to acheive what you want 
I have added a div outside your main box (#label1) whose id is #borderbox

**and change your css as below**

```
#borderbox{
   position: relative; 
    top: 42px; 
    left: 105px; 
    width: 60px; 
    height: 60px; 
    background-color:rgb(165, 165, 165);
    padding:10px;
}

#label1{
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    background: none repeat scroll 0px 0px rgb(170, 175, 255);
}
```

now what you are describing your problem is **you want to increase the border width**
as of now you can increase the **padding of `#borderbox`** that will appear as the border to the main box

here is a working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uttara/cSvXP/6/)**

Comment: thanks for it , but i need that To increase border width at that time box size will not increase  so that mean border-boxing ... how to make it ...?

Comment: `box-sizing:border-box` causes the border width to be included in the width of the element itself i.e (if `width:60px` and `border-width:10px`, resultant width will be `60px` and actual width of the box will be `50px`, so when you increase the `border-width` the actual width of the box will decrease). Is this what you want??

Comment: yes , when i add increase  border size that time box size will same . that mean box size become same ...

Comment: really not getting what your problem is.. you can just increase the `padding of div#borderbox` (in demo) and it is not causing the size of your main box to increase.. it is same isn't it

Comment: but main div is whole div .. ( user display one div ... ) so i increase  padding then increase  size of whole div ...

Comment: check if this is your requirement [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uttara/cSvXP/8/).. just change the `padding` of `#borderbox` and the size remains the same

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15747/discussion-between-kamlesh0606-and-uttara)

Answer (score 0):

I Guess this is wat you are looking for

http://jsfiddle.net/kamlesh0606/jrQ7A/1/

```
<div style="position: relative; top: 42px; left: 105px; width: 60px; height: 60px; border: 10px solid rgb(165, 165, 165); background: none repeat scroll 0px 0px rgb(170, 175, 255);" id="label1" class="drag">
```